# Is it possible an IIS server could be unable to make requests to a site, but the server box be able to?

Tags: iis, recaptcha

I'm getting HTTP error codes when I'm trying to make a request from ReCaptcha on a server I'm trying to configure.

I'm a bit of a newbie, but I was wondering if despite me being able to access the page from IE, it would be unable to access it via the IIS server running the code?

I'm just trying to eliminate potentially causes of the issue.

Comment: To clarify, I don't mean like 405 etc error codes, I mean I'm getting WinHttp.WinHttpRequest: A connection with the server could not be established

Comment: You have to learn what is a session. The proxy setting in the user session that hosts the IE browser is completely different from the one in the system session where  web app is hosted on IIS.